# Offsetting ground texture doesn't work in WebGL

Tags: unity, c#, textures, webgl, side-scroller

so I've created a 2D sidescroller game, the technique I used is to keep the player on the same place, and move the obstacles towards him. I also offset the ground and backdrop constantly to create the illusion of player moving.

The ground texture is on a quad, and the texture wrap mode is set to repeat. 
In the editor everything is running fine as I wanted, however when I build it (WebGL), in the browser the ground doesn't seem as if it is set to Repeat but rather Clamp. 
Here's how it looks:

[image]

You can see from the left part of the image the ground doesn't repeat, the strange thing is that, after the game runs for a few more seconds it fixes, and then in a few seconds becomes like that again.

heres the code attached to the ground to keep it offsetting constantly:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Offset : MonoBehaviour {

public float scrollSpeed;
public Material mat;

private float offset;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    mat = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    offset = Mathf.Repeat(Time.time * scrollSpeed, 1);
    mat.mainTextureOffset = new Vector2(offset, mat.mainTextureOffset.y);
}
}
```

What may I be doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: based on my experience it's more convenient to use normal movement with spawning obstacles in front of character, so you don't need to sync other in-game objects with your ground texture offset

Comment: Would that be less performance heavy?

Comment: why you use Time.time ? Time.deltaTime is alot better ( for me )

Comment: Time.time only increases (which causes an increase in offset), where Time.deltaTime varies depending on the time in between frames

Comment: @VadimTatarnikov The performance different is slim. You should worry about performance only if you notice something wrong with it. At the end of the day, if it runs 0.0001 seconds faster, is it really worth it?

Answer (score 1):

for texture scrolling you should use "Repeat" in import settings instead of "clamp"

Comment: I have done that